# numeric marks field validation

Tags: javascript

I want numeric javascript validation for marks field.
Marks entered should be out of 5 means user can enter upto 5 marks not more than that.
marks may be in decimal like 4.25
after decimal there should be 2 digits can any one help me..

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is probably `value.toString().match(/^[0-5](\.\d{1,2})?$/)`.  Generally you want to avoid regular expressions, but this will save you several otherwise exhaustive steps to validate the format of the number.

Comment: @Sachin Shanbhag's answer is a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

Check this code -

```
if( Number(str) < 0 || Number(str).toFixed(2) > 5 ) {
    //Throw error
}
```

where `str` is your value to be validated.

Answer (score 0):

`Mark: <input type="text" id="mark" onBlur="validateMark()">`

```
function validateMark() {
    var val = document.getElementById('mark').value;
    if (!val.match(/^[0-5](\.\d{1,2})?$/)) {
        alert("Invalid mark: " + val);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Input field length**

You can set the maximal length of the input field like this:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="5" placeholder="12345" />
```

Or, if you want to have max 5 characters, 1 separator, AND 2 decimals:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="8" placeholder="12345.12" />
```

**The javascript validations:**

The quick solution (allows comma's + dots, maxlength=5)

```
var value = "15,5";
if(!isNaN(parseFloat(value)) && value.length <= 5) {
    console.log('valid, continue');
}
```

If you only want to allow dots, add an extra 'isFinite' check

```
var value = "145.5";
if(!isNaN(parseFloat(value)) && isFinite(value) && value.length <= 5) {
    console.log('valid, continue');
}
```

**--- NOTE the following! ---**

If you mean that just the **first** digits (not including the decimals!) can have a maxlength of 5, then forget the above.

You first want to check if the input is numeric, then force the two digits.
At last you can check if the length is lower or equal to 8 (5 digits + 1 separator + 2 decimals = 8)

```
var value = "12345.58852"; // Input field (string)

if(!isNaN(parseFloat(value)) && isFinite(value) && parseFloat(value).toFixed(2).length <= 8) {
    console.log('valid, continue');
}
```

To make it complete, here is a function to check if a variable is numeric

(Test: **http://jsfiddle.net/web_nfo/CBKwA/**)

```
function isNumeric(value, strict)
{
    var strict = (typeof strict == 'undefined' ? false : (strict == true ? true : false));
    if(strict && typeof value != 'number') {
        return false;
    }
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(value)) && isFinite(value);
}
```

If you include the function you can rewrite the last check like this:

```
if(isNumeric(value) && parseFloat(value).toFixed(2).length <= 8) {
    console.log('valid, continue');
}
```